# What is the difference between "compile" and "build" in Go?

Tags: go

What is the accurate difference between "compile" and "build" in Golang?

Comment: `go build` compiles.

Comment: There is no `compile` command. The `go` tool does compile packages when you `build` or `install` (or `test`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `go` command internally calls an internal tool called `compile` which produces so-called "object files" from the source code files. It then calls the internal tool called `link` which takes those object code files and produces a final executable image file or a package—depending on what is being built.

I think you should start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_(computing)), then [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) and then run the `go build` command passing it the `-x` command-line parameter, making it verbosely print what is does.